# Append Items to an Insight Object Attribute

Tags: jira

We are trying to write a post function to append items to an Insight Object Attribute.

We have used the sample code but it overwrites the existing attribute. Also only one value (the first one in the field) is set as attribute

```
/* Get Insight Object Attribute Facade from plugin accessor */
Class objectTypeAttributeFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectTypeAttributeFacade");
def objectTypeAttributeFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(objectTypeAttributeFacadeClass);


/* Get the factory that creates Insight Attributes */
Class objectAttributeBeanFactoryClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.factory.ObjectAttributeBeanFactory");
def objectAttributeBeanFactory = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(objectAttributeBeanFactoryClass);

/* This is the custom field with the value you want to add to an object attribute */
CustomField jiraCustomField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(13613); // Employees to Give Access

/* This is the custom field where the object/s you want to set the value */
CustomField insightCustomField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(13679); // Database (my) - Owner
def insightObjects = issue.getCustomFieldValue(insightCustomField); // "issue" variable is always accessible in post function scripts.

/* This is the Database object type attribute (Access) and the one we want to modify */
def objectTypeAttributeBean = objectTypeAttributeFacade.loadObjectTypeAttributeBean(2528);


if (insightObjects != null) {
insightObjects.each{insightObject ->
/* Create the new attribute bean based on the value */
def newValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(jiraCustomField);
def newObjectAttributeBean = objectAttributeBeanFactory.createObjectAttributeBeanForObject(insightObject, objectTypeAttributeBean, newValue[0].getName());

/* Load the attribute bean */
def objectAttributeBean = objectFacade.loadObjectAttributeBean(insightObject.getId(), objectTypeAttributeBean.getId());

if (objectAttributeBean != null) {

/* If attribute exist reuse the old id for the new attribute */
newObjectAttributeBean.setId(objectAttributeBean.getId());
}
/* Store the object attribute into Insight. */
try {
objectAttributeBean = objectFacade.storeObjectAttributeBean(newObjectAttributeBean);
} catch (Exception vie) {
log.warn("Could not update object attribute due to validation exception:" + vie.getMessage());
}
}
}

/* Done! :) */
return true;
```